# showing entries based on selection type in django

Tags: django, postgresql

my question is  i want to show only particular titles under music_track (musicmodel)field when type = track(title model) in my django admin site

```
class album(models.Model):
  def get_autogenerated_code():
    last_id = album.objects.values('id').order_by('id').last()
    if not last_id:
      return "AL-"+str(0)
    return "AL-"+str(last_id['id'])
  album_name = models.CharField( max_length=150, blank=False )
  music_track = models.ManyToManyField("title")


  def __str__(self):
    return  (self.album_name)

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Album"
    verbose_name_plural = "Albums"


class title(models.Model):
  def get_autogenerated_code():
    last_id = title.objects.values('id').order_by('id').last()
    if not last_id:
      return "TT-"+str(0)
    return "TT-"+str(last_id['id'])
  upc_code = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="N/A", blank=False)
  display_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
  type = models.ForeignKey(Asset_Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)


  def __str__(self):
    return  (self.display_name+ " " +self.code)


  admin.site.register( [album, title] )
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I am understanding that while creating an `album` in your `admin panel`, you require that the `music_track` should only show the `titles` having type as `track`. My solution for this is:

***In your `admin.py` file***

```
from .models import title, album, Asset_type

class AlbumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ('album_name', 'music_track', )

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AlbumForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        type = Asset_type.objects.get(type='track')
        self.fields['music_track'].queryset = Title.objects.filter(type=type)

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AlbumForm

admin.site.register(album, MyModelAdmin)
```

Maybe this can give you the idea you need.

Comment: i didn't use forms in my app

Comment: This form is for the admin panel

Comment: hi bro , thanks for your response , i have one doubt what is the queryset in your code (        self.fields['music_track'].queryset = Title.objects.filter(type=type)
)

Comment: The queryset ensures that the field music track contains Title objects with type as specified.